Using WebRTC Trickle ICE with JavaScript client and Python server causes incompatible ICE candidate structure
I'm creating an application for live video detection where one peer is the client and the other peer is the server. I've established a working peer connection with WebRTC but the current problem is the latency it takes for a connection to establish. The latency is caused by WebRTC waiting 5-10 seconds after gathering all ICE candidates, so Trickle ICE seemed like a good solution. However, I've encountered problems with adding the ICE candidate to the server's peer connection. I use Socket.IO to emit the candidate to the server, but the structure of the candidate sent from the JS client seems to be incompatible with what RTC expects in Python.
The candidate looks like this on the server:
{'candidate': 'candidate:0 1 UDP 2122187007 10.129.98.164 60257 typ host', 'sdpMid': '0', 'sdpMLineIndex': 0, 'usernameFragment': 'b65825c5'}

I tried to create a new RTCIceCandidate object using the candidate data received from the client, but I get the following error:
candidate:0 1 UDP 2122187007 10.129.98.164 64948 typ host
init() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'foundation', 'ip', 'port', 'priority', 'protocol', and 'type'

Now I understand that the missing positional arguments are the values of the key 'candidate' (as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidate/candidate), and that I can access them by parsing them in the server and just create a new candidate object with these values. But my question is if this is the ideal solution? Will this work every time, or can the structure of the candidate change under different circumstances?
